# How would you implement a table that shows only selected cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Ive got a button on each table cell that gets selected:

```
@IBAction func tickAction(sender: UIButton) {
    println("SSSS")

    if (sender.selected) {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Unchecked.png"), forState: .Normal)
        sender.selected = false

    }
    else {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Checked.png"), forState: .Normal)
        sender.selected = true



    }
}
```

I am trying to find a way to make a table where only the selected cells are shown..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have the selected state in the view, but in the model.

Let's say your current UITableView has a data source that's an array of Article's, let's call it `articles` and let's say an Article is:

```
class Article {
    let name: String
    var selected: Bool = false

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

//Example
let a = Article(name: "Article A")
let b = Article(name: "Article B")
let c = Article(name: "Article C")
b.selected = true

let articles = [a, b, c]
```

Then, your second UITableView with only the selected Articles will have a data source of:

```
let selectedArticles = articles.filter{ $0.selected } // Only contains 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

So, normally, we have a single array that we're using for the data source to show the rows.

Here, you'll want a second array to keep track of the checked cells.  When a cell becomes selected, dump it in this array.  When it becomes unselected, remove it from this array.

Now, based on whether you want to show all cells or just selected cells, that determines which array you're using, so you'll have logic like scattered throughout your datasource/delegate methods:

```
var dataSourceArray: Array<CustomDataObject>
if showingSelectedOnly {
    dataSourceArray = self.selectedCells
} else {
    dataSourceArray = self.allCells
}
```

And then use this array for things like number of rows in section, cell for index path, etc.

Comment: got a completely seperate table just for selected.

Comment: The basic logic is the same, and what you want exactly seems pretty unclear, but either way, you should still be able to take what I've explained and figure the last half step out by yourself.  There's no magic way of doing it.  You need to keep track of what data you want to display in the table, and tell the table to display that data.  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not place the column which contains the **selected** attribute into the original data table, instead of using a separate table?